# On Cloudflare Pages KV, how do you seed values for KV keys

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-workers, cloudflare-pages, cloudflare-kv

I have a Cloudflare Pages project with functions which used KV.  I wish to test my functions with KV values that are seeded before the function is called.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:
On the root directory of your project … i.e. where the functions directory is, create a file in a directory:

```
.wrangler/state/kv/<bind-name>/<key>
```

<bind-name> is your KV namespace.
<key> is a file with the name of your key.

for me bind-name is TEST, key is BUG_TEST. So my file is:

```
.wrangler/state/kv/TEST/BUG_TEST
```

Inside the file place the value for the key.

Then when you start your wrangler use --persist. For me, using pages, the command is:

```
npx wrangler pages dev --kv=TEST --persist -- npm start
```

Also, if you are using git don’t forget to add .wrangler to .gitignore

Comment: Thanks for sharing, this works for v2. Have you got this working for wrangler/miniflare v3?

Comment: I did not get this working for v3 and abandoned the method.